# jquery reference vairable while targeting a class with an effect

Tags: jquery

```
let cur = jQuery(this).closest('.step');
let next = jQuery(cur).next();
       
jQuery(next).show(".header");
```

Is this valid jquery? Its not doing anything at all but has no errors. If its not right, then how do I reference the variable while also targeting the header class with the show?

Comment: added above the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it isn't valid jQuery:

- `cur` and `next` are jQuery objects and therefor they should not be put again in a jQuery object. It should be `next = cur.next();` and `next.show(...`.
- `show()` accepts only speed, easing and callback as params but no selector. The function `show()` adds `display: none` to the element it is attached to.

If `.header` is inside `next` the code block would be:

```
let cur = jQuery(this).closest('.step');
let next = cur.next();
       
next.find(".header").show();
```

Comment: ok thank you. so what is the proper display of this then?

Comment: Thank you very much that makes sense and was the answer

Comment: One of the strong points of jQuery is its "chainability": So, you could write the whole thing without using a single variable as: `$(this).closest('.step').next().find(".header").show()`.